# Is it possible with Google searches to ban any and all results from a domain?

Tags: google-search

Is it possible to configure Google somehow to **permanently** ban search results from domains that I know 100% are never, ever going to make me happy?  Something cookie/session based maybe?

E.g. I want to ban (permanently, forever and always) results from `experts-exchange.com`.  Every time I click results that take me to their page I just want to scream.

---

**Update!**  Google has released a Chrome Extension to allow users to block individual site from Google search results!  [Personal Blocklist (by Google)](http://bit.ly/dOCLuI).  *(Since this question has been closed, I cannot answer it.)*

[image]

Comment: Not to be a complete dork or anything, but experts-exchange does have the answer to the question for free at the bottom.  I didn't realize this for a long time.

Comment: @Peter Turner: Not always. If you are referred from google it does, but if your referrer isn't sent, or you are not coming from google, it doesn't.

Comment: @Macha - You mean you directly went to the hyphen site? That seems self-defeating! =)

Comment: [Is there a way to tell Google I don't want results from a certain website?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/29559)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you can probably do this with Google's Custom Search Engine...

http://www.google.com/cse

Comment: This is how I eliminate Experts Exchange.

Comment: My custom search engine is http://www.google.com/coop/cse?cx=013033296181757682315:8ufu3l2e4d0

Comment: This is a good solution if u want to keep adding to the list of sites you want to exclube, the -site:blah.com option is better for a single search

Comment: @Roy if i would be the one writing your comment i would say -site.experts-exchange.com instead of blah

Comment: It does not allows me to insert `-site:twitter.com` so it does the opposite of what I'm looking for... I can search 'only on twitter' but cannot search 'never on twitter'.

Comment: @LeighRiffel How did you specify your CSE to always exclude this specific domaing that you mentioned?

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah - There is a sites to exclude section in the search engine definition.

Comment: @LeighRiffel Sorry, but I'm not seeing this section on my screen on https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/controlpanel/create . Could you please add a screenshot of your screen to the 2009 reply?

Comment: I found out how to do it: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/134858/298035

Answer (score 32):

If you use the -site: directive in your searches it will not list them

> my search -site:experts-exchange.com

I'm not sure how to make it permanent though

Comment: I wish I could up-vote you. I'm all out for the day though.

Comment: @Jonathan: I still had some left for you ;)

Comment: +1 me too :-d ...  more chars

Comment: expert sex change most annoying site on the web

Comment: Daniweb is also dislikable.

Answer (score 15):

If your browser of choice supports being able to edit the quick search bars, you can edit or add in the searches with the following:

```
http://www.google.com.au/search?q=%s+-site:experts-exchange.com
```

That way you'd be able to use the browser search bar/helper and not have to remind yourself that you want nothing to do with that site other than to not see it in your results.

You can tweak it for any other number of sites, just remembering to add it into the address line, like:

```
http://www.google.com.au/search?q=%s+-site:example.com+-site:example.org
```

Comment: Ahh this is what I meant :)

Answer (score 3):

The [CustomizeGoogle](http://www.customizegoogle.com/) Firefox extension helps to filter search results

This is probably the easiest way i found ,rather than typing operators for each and every search

Answer (score 1):

Also, to alleviate the `experts-exchange.com` woes, you can tell your browser to block cookies from the site.  Then you can scroll to the bottom of any page to see the "expert" answers.

Comment: I have also set up an Adblock rule to hide the entire ad/hidden answer block.  It's actual semi-usable with all the garbage hidden :)

Comment: To block all access you can also put this line in the "hosts" file (location varies, but it may be in folder C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc): 127.0.0.1       www.experts-exchange.com

Comment: Blocking using the hosts file will not allow you to see any content on that site, though.

Answer (score 1):

You do know that the answers there are always and forever visible in plain text if you scroll all the way to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1):

There's a Firefox add-on called [BlockSite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3145) that I used to use. You just input the domain and it will make sure no traffic to or from that domain will be through your computer.

It even goes so far as to make links to that domain plaintext so you can't even click on them.

Sadly, it's not supported by the latest versions of Firefox. Maybe someone has an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing a -experts-exchange.com in your Google query?

Edit:

Google's rule of thumb:

> The rule of thumb
>
> Each site on the Web is controlled by
>   its own webmaster. If you find a page
>   in Google's search results that you'd
>   like to see changed, your best bet is
>   to contact the webmaster and ask him
>   or her to make a change.

It'd be funny for Experts Exchange to get a bunch of queries concerning this!

Comment: I don't want to have to type that with every query that might end up with them in the results.