# How to filter Google search results?

Tags: windows, firefox, google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible with Google searches to ban any and all results from a domain?](https://superuser.com/questions/5631/is-it-possible-with-google-searches-to-ban-any-and-all-results-from-a-domain)

Is there a way to exclude permanently and FOREVER some domain names from being shown in google search result page except using geasemonkey + a script ?

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/5631/is-it-possible-with-google-searches-to-ban-any-and-all-results-from-a-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice add-on for Firefox called [surfclarity](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12305) witch filter searchs results on google and yahoo ...

Answer (score 7):

Probably the best way to do this is with the [SearchWiki](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115764) feature. If you sign in to your Google account, you can disable a result.

[image: SearchWiki]

Comment: +1, I have used this mostly for "the hypen" site `:-)`.

Comment: this doesn't block the domain name.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply prefix the `site:` search modifier with a minus sign.

Searching for "Something -site:somesite.org" does work.

Comment: im looking for something which block that a given list of domain names each time i do a research.

Comment: The easiest which I can imagine to do that would be that you create a small page you can set as your home page which contains just a search box that automatically appends numerous "-site:something" to the search string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use, Stylish to write your own style (css) and block certain results on-load. gluck