# Blocking Experts-Exchange from my Google results and/or computer

Tags: firefox, blocking, blacklist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible with Google searches to ban any and all results from a domain?](https://superuser.com/questions/5631/is-it-possible-with-google-searches-to-ban-any-and-all-results-from-a-domain)

The site Experts-Exchange is **very** annoying. How can I block it from my Google results? Alternatively, how can I block it in Firefox, so that if I click on a link to it, I instantly see that it's blocked? That way, I won't be annoyed by it after I see the page load and scroll down to see answers being blocked off >_>

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/5631/is-it-possible-with-google-searches-to-ban-any-and-all-results-from-a-domain

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tip of the day: Scroll **all** the way to the bottom of their pages to see the unhidden answers...

Comment: Don't they track this, though? Just when you're starting to feel slightly benevolent towards them and you've visited the site x number of times they hide the answers again and ask you to register.

Comment: This doesn't always work, I've seen cases where the bottom part is missing. However if you switch user agent to googlebot it always works (or at least it did so far).

Comment: Now apply some Adblock (or userstyles, or Greasemonkey) and you won't even need to scroll down.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [**this**](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/9462) Greasemonkey script to block it from Google search results. Greasemonkey is an add-on for Firefox which you can grab [**here**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748).

Comment: Sadly your link is dead and it's a little bit different to search for "this" using some search engine. Do you still remember the name of the script that were talking about?

Answer (score 6):

The [CustomizeGoogle](http://www.customizegoogle.com/) Firefox extension allows, among other things, to filter websites from the search results. It's one of the things I miss the most about FF.

Answer (score 3):

When typing in your search specify "-experts-exchange".

Comment: good, but not practical to type all the time

Answer (score 2):

If you clicked on the Google Cached answer for EE, it MUST contain the actual answers (but at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 1):

> or maybe block from firefox so if i click it i instantly see that its blocked

1. Open c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts in Notepad
2. Add the following line:

   127.0.0.1 www.experts-exchange.com

When a user browses to www.experts-exchange.com in any browser, they will be referred to the localhost's ip address and should get a blank page.

Comment: Why the negative vote on this question?

Comment: Question references removing the result from the search, not blocking access to the domain in question.

Comment: I guess as it doesn't keep the results from appearing in Google? It does block it from Firefox though, which indeed was the author's alternative question: *maybe block from firefox so if i click it i instantly see that its blocked*.