# How to make Google Search look dumb?

Tags: google-search

I know its a silly question,but i want the search results to be intentionally inaccurate.

Sorry, i am not fluent in english,so i will explain using the  images below with `Breaking Bad` tv series as an example :

[image]

[image]

Using (-) sign I can exclude unwanted results,but dont want the other users become aware of it

Any script and software that can help me achieve this?

Edit- I am leaning more towards Fiddler,Are there any Fiddler Gurus around here that can help me,perphaps i can(please tell me if this is against the rules) hire someone.

@krowe - I think the Fiddler way  is more suitable for me,but really really thank you for helping me.

Comment: Which browser do you need this to work on?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Is it possible with Google searches to ban any and all results from a domain?](http://superuser.com/questions/5631/is-it-possible-with-google-searches-to-ban-any-and-all-results-from-a-domain)

Comment: @Dave - This question is not only about google but also every known search engine

Comment: @nasekt Well, that definitely makes it too broad at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/index.php?version=3.8.52&ext=dhdg&updated=true) in Chrome (or [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) in Firefox). Something like this should do it:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Tamper with Google Results
// @namespace  http://superuser.com/users/145045/krowe
// @version    0.1
// @description  This just modifies google results to exclude certain things.
// @match      http://*.google.com
// @match      https://*.google.com
// @copyright  2014+, KRowe
// ==/UserScript==


function GM_main () {
    window.onload = function () {
      var targ = window.location;
      if(targ && targ.href && targ.href.match('https?:\/\/www.google.com/.+#q=.+') && targ.href.search("/+-torrent/+-watch/+-download")==-1) {
        targ.href = targ.href +"+-torrent+-watch+-download";
      }
    };
}

//-- This is a standard-ish utility function:
function addJS_Node(text, s_URL, funcToRun, runOnLoad) {
    var D=document, scriptNode = D.createElement('script');
    if(runOnLoad) scriptNode.addEventListener("load", runOnLoad, false);
    scriptNode.type = "text/javascript";
    if(text) scriptNode.textContent = text;
    if(s_URL) scriptNode.src = s_URL;
    if(funcToRun) scriptNode.textContent = '(' + funcToRun.toString() + ')()';
    var targ = D.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild(scriptNode);
}

addJS_Node (null, null, GM_main);
```

This has only been tested in Chrome. Also, this doesn't work everywhere. For example, if you search from the start page instead of the location bar it will not work because the page load event doesn't fire. I'm not sure if this can be fixed or not.

I've done nothing to actually hide what is happening. I'd imagine that getting the URL to show the original results would be easy to do if you replace the page content with a frame and instead of the redirect you just load the new page into the frame. Getting the search box to work right is going to be a little more tricky but in the end is also very doable. The trick is going to be to use CSS to hide it then make another textbox to be seen. Then you'l just need to add a few event handlers to sync the real search box with your fake search box. User scripts can also be used without an extensions in Chrome but I have no experience with doing that because those scripts are not supposed to be cross browser compatible and these are. If you really want this hidden that is probably going to be something you want to do as well. Otherwise, the extension is always going to be visible to anyone who looks for it. You can hide the button for the extension though by right clicking on it.

Comment: Another crazy thought,Can i use something like man-in-the-middle proxy(like fiddler)? For example, creating FiddlerScript or something like that?   Thank you for taking your time to help me.

Comment: Something like that should be possible. I don't have experience doing that though.

Comment: @nasekt I have used Privoxy to make a flat mate's facebook page look very personal.. hell of a prank.  Or to make Google look silly like adding a Os to google. But not for making Google search inaccurate.

Comment: @barlop - I have tried several scripts and softwares for filtering results,but none of them come close to this method.If  this method works i will be a happy man.

Comment: @nasekt well, try krowe's script, and keep us updated

Comment: @krowe- I copied the script to tampermonkey and saved it,then clicked home page(google.com) typed `Breaking Bad`,not working.Tried it several times,Can you please tell what went wrong?

Comment: @nasekt I have no idea why I didn't get a notification for this response but I believe the problem is that you MUST type the search string in the address bar for this to work. The problem with typing into Google search directly is that the `onload` event doesn't fire. You could fix that by responding to the textbox onchange event as well.

Comment: @krowe I have posted my question on 15 different forums,All they say is they have no idea on how to hide the search query.I have a small request for you,I am not fluent in english and cannot express my words corretly,SO can you please post my question in your own words at stackoverflow?(I don't know why but i am banned from asking futher questions)

Comment: @nasekt Sorry, I won't post my own questions on SO any more because they are insane over there. As a person who uses many of the SE sites, I'm also not a big fan of cross posting (except in a few rare cases). To make things even worse, this question is basically asking how to make a tool for an evil genius. I'm just not into getting that involved in it.

Comment: @krowe I got some helpful information from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441565/how-do-i-make-a-div-element-editable-like-a-textarea-when-i-click-it#2441686 (Is there a way to improve this script to solve my problem?)

Comment: What do you think about this: http://imgur.com/JdKLgkR,gbRUpjS,P9dV4Za#0

Answer (score 0):

Google has an extension for Chrome called [Personal Blocklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef?hl=en). It doesn't quite allow for what you requested (blocking based on keywords), but it does allow for you to block certain domains from appearing in search results.
[image: Personal Blocklist Extension Preview]

Comment: @Dracs- There are hundreds of unwanted sites that i want to be blocked.I don't want to manually block each site by hand. Is there a solution for that? Thank you for your time.